# Нужно скачать большое количество файлов txt (около 400) с сайта

Tags: php, download

Здраствуйте. Есть сайт, на котором в отдельных ссылках содержатся файлы txt. На каждый файл - отдельная ссылка. Вот только эти ссылки отличаются только одной цифрой. То есть https:// .....1.txt, https:// .....2.txt, и так до 400. Можно ли скачать их всех разом? Есть ли какой-то скрипт для скачивания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал на коленке, должно работать:

```
$url = ''; // Ввести URL без названия файлов
$dir = 'storage';
$ext = 'txt';

is_dir($dir) ?: mkdir($dir);
$view = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < 400; $i++) {
    $file = "$url/{$i}.$ext";
    $content = @ file_get_contents($file);
    if ($content !== false && file_put_contents("$dir/{$i}.$ext", $content)) {
        $view ?: $view = 'Записаны файл(ы):<br>';
        $view .= "{$i}.$ext<br>";
    }
}

echo $view;
```